# GWT DataGrid not correctly overwriting rows when whole list replaced

Tags: java, gwt, datagrid

**Update 2:** Answered my own question below

---

**Update:** I have verified that the `getValue()` method in the grid's columns are returning the correct values - those in the database, and not those made by local edits. In other words, the value returned by `getValue` is **not** the value displayed in the `DataGrid` itself. Is there something I'm not refreshing/updating? How could this happen?

---

I have a `DataGrid` which I am updating using the methods `setRowCount()` and `setRowData()`. The objects represented in the grid are mutable, and all columns have a corresponding `FieldUpdater`, which directly modify the objects in the list passed to the `DataGrid`. The grid is re-populated with a fresh database query (and fresh list of objects, completely distinct from the old list) when required by the user.

Everything was working fine until I implemented the ability to make local per-row changes and then commit them when necessary. When the commit occurs, the database is updated with the values from the object currently at that row. If a cell is modified but the commit is not initiated, the object held in the list is modified but no database modifications are made.

The issue is that for some reason, if the current list being shown by the `DataGrid` holds local, uncommitted values, when the `DataGrid` is refreshed it still contains local values that weren't committed, when I would expect these to revert to the database values. The list being set to the `DataGrid` contains the correct, database values, but for some reason these are being ignored. The values only update to the database values when the whole page is refreshed in the browser (which of course re-loads everything/clears memory etc).

The update code I am using is below - I have added a few potentially unnecessary steps but all to no avail. No matter what I set on the input list, the `DataGrid` shows the local values.

```
private void update(List<TheObject> newRows) {
    // newRows contains the correct database-side committed values and none of the local, uncommitted values

    dataGrid.setRowCount(0, true);
    dataGrid.setRowData(java.util.Collections.<TheObject> emptyList());
    dataGrid.redraw();
    // at this point, dataGrid.getVisibleItems() returns an empty list

    dataGrid.setRowCount(newRows.size(), true);
    dataGrid.setRowData(newRows);
    dataGrid.redraw();
    // at this point, dataGrid.getVisibleItems() returns a list containing the database values and none of the local values, which is correct
}
```

Once this method completes however, the grid still shows local values that weren't committed - despite `getVisibleItems()` always showing the correct, database values without any of the local values. Essentially there is a definite miss-match between what should be displayed according to the list passed to `setRowData()`, and what is actually displayed.

There are several other important/interesting points:

- The objects contained in the new list are absolutely different object instances than those that were contained in the old list.
- If an uncaught exception is thrown during the `update()` method *after* the grid has row count set to zero (resulting in an empty table), when the method is next called successfully the local values are correctly replaced by the database values.
- Based on the above, I have tried putting all the code after the grid is cleared into a `scheduleDeferred()` method. However, the issue still exists.
- The objects held by the grid share the same static `KeyProvider`, and and new values sent to the grid will by this provider have the **same key** as values that already existed before the grid was cleared. Could this be something to do with it?

I realise that a common answer may be "I had this issue and then I used a ListDataProvider and it fixed it", but for reasons which would warrant an entire new question this is not currently possible.

Any help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be fixed. In order to get the correct behaviour, I added a call to`dataGrid.redraw()` inside each column's `FieldUpdater`. That's it.

```
someColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<TheObject, String>() {

    @Override
    public void update(int index, TheObject object, String value) {

        object.setSomeValue(value);
        dataGrid.redraw();
    }
});
```

I have no idea why this should be necessary, but there you go. Any thoughts on this would still be appreciated because it has left me a little untrusting of the whole GWT thing...

Thanks for all those who read the question.